# How does the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{x^2} \right) \,\text{d}x$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I tried using the fact that $\ln(f(x)) < f(x)$ but that doesn't seem to work. It's an improper integral.
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{x^2} \right) \,\text{d}x
$$

Comment: $\ln(1+1/x^2)$ has an explicit antiderivative. The key to this approach is to investigate a term like $x\ln(1+1/x^2)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: You could instead use the inequality $x-1 \geq \ln (x)$.

Comment: Also setting $t=\frac 1{x^2}$ will probably help

Comment: Actually, if $y>1$, then $0<\ln y < y-1$. That should help.

Comment: Wait! I don't think this thing converges because of the $0$ in the lower limit of integration!

Comment: According to Wolfram, the integral has value $\pi$. The antiderivate is $xln(1+\frac{1}{x^2})+2tan^{-1}(x)$

Comment: @bob1123 : to show $\ln x$ is integrable on $]0;1]$ you can use $|\ln x| < 1/x^a$ for any $a > 0$ (or you can look at its antiderivative $x \ln x - x + C$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\int \ln(1+\frac{1}{x^2}) dx = x \log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+1\right)+2 \arctan (x) + C$$ so
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \ln(1+\frac{1}{x^2}) dx \\ &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( x \log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+1\right)+2 \arctan (x) \right) - \lim_{x \to 0} \left(x \log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+1\right)+2 \arctan (x) \right) \\ &= \left( 0 + 2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right) - \left( 0 + 0 \right) \\ &= \pi
\end{align} $$

Comment: For my edification, how did you get $\lim_{x \to \infty} x\log(\frac{1}{x^2} + 1) = 0$? I tried rewriting the expression to $x(\log(1+x^2) - \log(x^2))$ but I'm not sure that helps. Thanks!

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\log \left( \frac{1}{x^2} + 1 \right) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{1}{y} \log \left( y^2 + 1 \right) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y^2 + O(y^2)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0}  y + \frac{O(y)}{y} = 0 + 0 = 0$$

Comment: Thanks for the trick of changing $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ to $\lim_{y \to 0}$, I learned something new. Is there a way to reach the same answer without Taylor series which I haven't learned yet? If not, it's something to look forward to :)

Comment: You can apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to get$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\log \left( \frac{1}{x^2} + 1 \right) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\log \left( y^2 + 1 \right)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{y^2+1} \cdot 2y}{1} = 2 \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{y^2+1} = 2 \cdot \frac{0}{0+1} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to 0$, the integrand behaves as $-2 \log{x}$, which is an integrable singularity.

As $x \to \infty$, the integrand behaves as $1/x^2$, which is integrable in this limit.

There are no other singular points in the integration interval.

Answer (score 0):

To prove convergence, you should estimate behavior of the integrand near zero and near infinity.

Near zero $\ln(1 + x^{-2}) \approx \ln(x^{-2}) = -2 \ln x $. It is known that $\int \ln x \; dx$ converges near zero.

Near infinity $\ln(1 + x^{-2}) \approx x^{-2}$. It is known that $\int x^{-2} \; dx$ converges near infinity.

So the integral converges properly. In fact, notation $f(x) \approx g(x)$ should be replaced with more strict $f(x) = \Theta(g(x))$ everywhere.